# Function to calculate timespan for a certain event

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this

```
timestamp               phase
2019-07-01 07:10:00     a 
2019-07-01 07:11:00     a
2019-07-01 07:12:00     b
2019-07-01 07:13:00     b
2019-07-01 07:17:00     a
2019-07-01 07:19:00     a
2019-07-01 07:20:00     c
```

I am working on a function that creates a dataframe with an duration for every phase, till it hits the next phase.
I already have a solution but I have no clue how to write this in an **user-defined-function**, as I am new to python.

This is my "static" solution:

```
df['prev_phase'] = df["phase"].shift(1)
df['next_phase'] = df["phase"].shift(-1)

dfshift = df[df.next_phase != df.prev_phase]

dfshift["delta"] = (dfshift["timestamp"]-dfshift["timestamp"].shift()).fillna(0)

dfshift["helpcolumn"] = dfshift["phase"].shift(1)

dfshift2 = dfshift[dfshift.helpcolumn == dfshift["phase"]]

dfshift3 = dfshift2[["timestamp","phase","delta"]]

dfshift3["deltaminutes"] = dfshift3['delta'] / np.timedelta64(60, 's')
```

This gives me this as output (example):

```
timestamp            phase    delta             deltam
2019-05-01 06:44:00     a     0 days 04:51:00   291.0
2019-05-01 07:25:00     b     0 days 00:40:00   40.0
2019-05-01 21:58:00     a     0 days 14:32:00   872.0
2019-05-01 22:07:00     c     0 days 00:08:00   8.0
```

I just need this in a function.
Thanks in advance

Edit for @Tom

```
timestamp   phase
2019-05-05 08:58:00 a
2019-05-05 08:59:00 a
2019-05-05 09:00:00 b
2019-05-05 09:01:00 b
2019-05-05 09:02:00 b
2019-05-05 09:03:00 b
...
...
2019-05-05 09:38:00 b
2019-05-05 09:39:00 c
2019-05-05 09:40:00 c
2019-05-05 09:41:00 c
```

Those are the two colums + Index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp": ["2019-07-01 07:10:00",
                                "2019-07-01 07:11:00",
                                "2019-07-01 07:12:00", 
                                "2019-07-01 07:13:00", 
                                "2019-07-01 07:17:00", 
                                "2019-07-01 07:19:00",
                                "2019-07-01 07:20:00"],
                   "phase": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "a" ,"a", "c"]})
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])

# Create a 'phase_id' column to track when phase changes
df['phase_id'] = df['phase'].ne(df['phase'].shift()) + df.index

# Groupby new 'phase_id' variable and get time range for each phase
df_tdiff = df.groupby("phase_id").diff().reset_index()
df_tdiff.columns = ['phase_id', 'timediff']

# Merge this to old dataframe
df_new = pd.merge(df, df_tdiff, on=["phase_id"], how="left")
```

This then gives:

```
df_new
        timestamp       phase   phase_id    timediff
0   2019-07-01 07:10:00 a       1           00:01:00
1   2019-07-01 07:11:00 a       1           00:01:00
2   2019-07-01 07:12:00 b       3           00:01:00
3   2019-07-01 07:13:00 b       3           00:01:00
4   2019-07-01 07:17:00 a       5           00:02:00
5   2019-07-01 07:19:00 a       5           00:02:00
6   2019-07-01 07:20:00 c       7           NaT
```

Finally:

```
df_new = df_new.groupby("phase_id").first().reset_index(drop=True)

df_new
        timestamp       phase   timediff
0   2019-07-01 07:10:00 a       00:01:00
1   2019-07-01 07:12:00 b       00:01:00
2   2019-07-01 07:17:00 a       00:02:00
3   2019-07-01 07:20:00 c       NaT
```

Of course, if you need that all as a function (as originally requested), then:

```
def get_phase_timediff(df):
    # Create a 'phase_id' column to track when phase changes
    df['phase_id'] = df['phase'].ne(df['phase'].shift()) + df.index

    # Groupby new 'phase_id' variable and get time range for each phase
    df_tdiff = df.groupby("phase_id").diff().reset_index()
    df_tdiff.columns = ['phase_id', 'timediff']

    # Merge this to old dataframe
    df_new = pd.merge(df, df_tdiff, on=["phase_id"], how="left")

    # Groupby 'phase_id' again for final output
    df_new = df_new.groupby("phase_id").first().reset_index(drop=True)

    return(df_new)
```

Comment: Hi Tom, first of all thanks for your help. But somehow the first line "df['phase_id'] = df['phase'].ne(df['phase'].shift()).astype(int) + df.index" is not really working as it should. It just counts from 1 to 100, though the phase is not changing. Can you help me out? :)

Comment: @chwil Interesting. Is your `df` set up exactly the same way as mine? With just 2 columns - `timestamp` and `phase`? Post a longer sample in your original question (i.e. 20 rows) if you like and I'll take a look.